# JSON basic error

Tags: javascript, json, web

I'm doing a web dev class and I'm doing an excercise, it had included files that I've so far based my work on but I just noticed a json file I have to use, I've done basics HTML, CSS, JavaScript and JQuery over the past few weeks and have integrated all those files into my webpage fine, however with this json I'm not too sure what to do, nowhere near as many resources on the web about json compared to the rest so I was hoping someone here could help me out, I've tried including it in my webpage with

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='hall.json'></script>
```

My main issue is I can't get it working in dreamweaver, I get a syntax error on line 2

[image: a busy cat]

Here follows the JSON code

```
{
"who": "RSNO",
"what": "An American Festival",
"when": "2013-02-08 19:30",
"where": "User Hall - Main Auditorium",
"seats": [
    "00000000000000000011111111111111000000000000000000",
    "0000000000000001111111111111111aaa0000000000000000",
    "00000000000000aa111111111111111aaaaa00000000000000",
    "00000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000",
    "000000000aa00aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1100aa000000000",
    "00000001111001111111111111111111111100111100000000",
    "00000aaaaaa0011aaaaaaaaa11111111aaa1100aaaaaa00000",
    "00001111111001111111111111111111111100111111100000",
    "000aaaaaaa110011111111111111111111110011aaaaaaa000",
    "00111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111000",
    "00aaaaa1111110011111111111111111111001111aaaaaaa00",
    "11111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111110",
    "0aaaaaaaaaaaa001111111111111111111100aaaaaaaaaaaa0",
    "01111111111110011111111111111111110011111111111100",
    "00000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000000",
    "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100",
    "01111111111111001111111111111111110011111111111110",
    "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100",
    "00a11111111111100111111111111111100111111111111a00",
    "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000",
    "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000",
    "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000",
    "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000",
    "00011111111111110011111111111110011111111111110000",
    "0000000111a111111001111a1111a110011111111110000000",
    "00000000111111110011111111111110011111111000000000",
    "00000000001111111001111111111110011111110000000000",
    "00000000000000111001111111111100111000000000000000"
],
"rows": [
    "DD",
    "CC",
    "BB",
    "AA",
    "Z",
    "Y",
    "X",
    "W",
    "V",
    "U",
    "T",
    "S",
    "R",
    "Q",
    "P",
    "N",
    "M",
    "L",
    "K",
    "J",
    "H",
    "G",
    "F",
    "E",
    "D",
    "C",
    "B",
    "A"
],
"seatPrice": [
    "                  00000000000000                  ",
    "               0000000000000000000                ",
    "              0000000000000000000000              ",
    "             0000000000000000000000000            ",
    "         00  000000000000000000000000  00         ",
    "       0000  00000000000000000000000  0000        ",
    "     000000  000000000000000000000000  000000     ",
    "    0000000  00000000000000000000000  0000000     ",
    "   000000000  0000000000000000000000  000000000   ",
    "  0000000000  000000000000000000000  0000000000   ",
    "  00000000000  00000000000000000000  00000000000  ",
    "000000000000  000000000000000000000  000000000000 ",
    " 000000000000  00000000000000000000  000000000000 ",
    " 000000000000  0000000000000000000  000000000000  ",
    "                000000000000000000                ",
    " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ",
    " 0000000000000  000000000000000000  0000000000000 ",
    " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ",
    "  0000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000  ",
    "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ",
    "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ",
    "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ",
    "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ",
    "   0000000000000  0011111111100  0000000000000    ",
    "       0000000000  111111111111  0000000000       ",
    "        00000000  1111111111111  00000000         ",
    "          0000000  111111111111  0000000          ",
    "              000  00000000000  000               "
],
"priceLookup": [
    10,
    20
]
```

}

Comment: What are you doing with the json? Typically it's something you'd want to load via ajax if you're going to do work with it on the client side.

Comment: This is meant to be an easy basics sorta task, the JSON file has a hall layout, I've to design a seat booking page.
Like on this [LINK](http://ali-hassan.info)

Comment: JSON is just a way to structure your data. It's just like a csv file or an xml file or a word file or whatever. What you want to do with it is up to you. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation and it makes sense to use it in web development as and it is easy to work with. It is basically a Map with a bunch of key and value pairs. Since you are using jQuery you can use the `$.parseJSON()` method to convert all that text into an object. This object is a javascript object. If you do objectName.key you will get that keys particular value returned to you.

Comment: Any idea what dreamweavers problem is with line2? the syntax error?
Running it through JSON validators shows now issues

Comment: This is an invalid usage for a JSON file. You can include JSON file with AJAX. Check [this tutorial] (http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read through

Comment: @user1872493 - This is not the proper way to use json file. I have found this useful and genuine link - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLc7STlqyZm1rd7UI6xV0lNUvVXFmRjxSC

Answer (score 2):

You're not including the JSON properly on your page. JSON is not a language like javascript that gets interpreted or compiled, it is simply a data-representation language like XML or CSV. To use it in your page, you would make an ajax request for it and then use it in the `success` callback:

```
$.getJSON('hall.json', function (data) {
    var who = data.who; // "RSNO"
    var where = data.where; // "User Hall - Main Auditorium"
    // etc...
});
```

Note that `$.getJSON` performs an implicit `JSON.parse` for you, so `data` is already a javascript object, not a string.

See the [documentation for $.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is valid.

You get a syntax error because you're trying to interpret it as JavaScript.

You can write a script that read the JSON file and parses the content into a JavaScript object.

A very basic *example* is this:

```
httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpReq.open('GET','hall.json',false);
httpReq.send();

hall = JSON.parse(httpReq.responseText);
```

Then you can access the content with the JavaScript object notation:

```
who = hall.who; // 'RSNO'

seatsCount = hall.seats.length; // 28
```

And manipulate the DOM to dynamically build up or edit the web page to display the data (but this goes beyond the scope of the question...)

Answer (score 0):

Old Dreamweavers version make errors when:

```
{
"something":"content",
    "otherthing":"more content"
    }
```

So you have to use something like an array:

```
[{"something":"content","otherthing":"more content"}]
```

But lasts versions fix it. I'm using Dreamweaver CC 2015 now, and have putted all your code. It doesn't have mistakes now!